# Stable and latest version of Ubuntu Mate 18.04 for Raspberry Pi

Tags: 18.04, mate, raspberrypi, sd-card, versions

I have been looking for several days for a stable version of Ubuntu Mate 18.04 Desktop which I will use on my Raspberry Pi 3B.
In August, I was able to get Ubuntu Mate 18.04 from [ubuntu-mate.org/download/arm64/](http://ubuntu-mate.org/download/arm64/) and it worked smoothly. Anyway I was trying to use my RPi with a robot and for some reason I lost my SD card and replaced it.
Now I need the version I downloaded but I am not able to find it at the same place. 18.04 is removed and there are only 20.04 and 20.10.

I went through the "Browse Downloads" at the bottom of [ubuntu-mate.org/download/](http://ubuntu-mate.org/download/) and reached [releases.ubuntu-mate.org/archived/bionic/arm64](http://releases.ubuntu-mate.org/archived/bionic/arm64).
Anyway the image I downloaded and used (which is ubuntu-mate-18.04.2-beta1-desktop-arm64%2Braspi3-ext4.img.xz 24-Mar-2019 23:17) caused plenty of trouble and lost time to me. It required a partial upgrade (upgrade for more than 500 packages) and even after I solved plenty of problems it caused, it still gives errors.

Therefore, I believe this version is not the one I downloaded in August and used without any problem. I was wondering if anyone has the version I am looking for. I would be really happy if so.

By the way I checked Raspberry Pi for possible errors during robot installation, with several different SD cards and non gave any error. That is why I believe the Ubuntu Mate version I am using is the problem.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You might have better luck with the mini.iso and then choosing Mate as your desktop to install:  http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-arm64/current/images/netboot/  and these instructions tell you how to use the mini.iso  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=220079

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, there was no stable version for 18.04. You may try 20.04